# Load testing an API that uses pubsub

Tags: python, performance, locust

I'd like to use Locust to load test an API that uses pubsub. When I say that it uses pubsub, I mean:

- the entry point is a topic. Clients publish payloads to this topic
- The pubsub server then POST a request to my API
- my API aknowledges the request and answers with 200 (this does NOT mean that the request was processed)
- my API does some computations (they take ~20 seconds) and pubslishes a message on other topic
- I can link the original request and the response through a unique id

Basically, I need the client used by locust to send a request and then wait for a message to appear on the output topic.

Would you have an idea about how to do that with Locust?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the locust plugin for kafka (a type of pubsub) at [locust_plugins/users/kafka.py](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/users/kafka.py)

```py
import time
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from locust import User
import functools


class KafkaUser(User):
    abstract = True
    # overload these values in your subclass
    bootstrap_servers: str = None  # type: ignore

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.client: KafkaClient = KafkaClient(environment=environment, bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_servers)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.client.producer.flush(5)


def _on_delivery(environment, identifier, response_length, start_time, start_perf_counter, context, err, _msg):
    environment.events.request.fire(
        request_type="ENQUEUE",
        name=identifier,
        start_time=start_time,
        response_time=(time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000,
        response_length=response_length,
        context=context,
        exception=err,
    )


class KafkaClient:
    def __init__(self, *, environment, bootstrap_servers):
        self.environment = environment
        self.producer = Producer({"bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers})

    def send(self, topic: str, value: bytes, key=None, response_length_override=None, name=None, context={}):
        start_perf_counter = time.perf_counter()
        start_time = time.time()
        identifier = name if name else topic
        response_length = response_length_override if response_length_override else len(value)
        callback = functools.partial(
            _on_delivery, self.environment, identifier, response_length, start_time, start_perf_counter, context
        )
        self.producer.produce(topic, value, key, on_delivery=callback)
        response_length = response_length_override if response_length_override else len(value)

        self.producer.poll()
```

If you can define your custom Producer other than the one from confluent_kafka as shown above, you can test like in the [example](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/kafka_ex.py)